# why do I use the relative clause made instead of using the passive form "are made"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Does he like clothes made of cotton?

Why can't I use the passive form here and say

> Does he like clothes are made of cotton?

Answer (score 1):

> *Why can't I use the passive form here and say "Does he like clothes are made of cotton?*

I don't understand what you mean by "passive form" in this case.

Anyway,

The reason you can't do so is because you would be mangling the clause *Does he like clothes made of cotton* in that case.

Basically, the full clause is *which are made of cotton* and its abbreviated version the one you've used. You could read more about such clauses under *Reduced Relative Clauses.*

I hope it's easy to see now why your version doesn't work.

Comment: In other words, _made of cotton_ acts as an adjective describing a particular type of clothes.

Comment: That's right, @Kate Bunting.